# Origin of the term Riesz Basis

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

The term Riesz basis is in wide use for the image of an orthonormal basis in a Hilbert space under a bounded invertible map (there are lots of equivalent definitions).  But I've been unable to find any papers by either Riesz on this subject.  Does anyone know a reference that justifies the name or otherwise know of a first use or something that sheds light on the origins of this term?

Answer (score 5):

According to the article [Riesz system](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Riesz_system) in the [EoM](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.com/), some early references that use this term are from N.K. Bari (or Bary). The 1946 reference seems hard to locate online, but the [1951](http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/uzmu/v148/p69) reference in Russian can be. I can confirm that she uses the terms *Bessel system*, *Hilbert system*, *Fischer-Riesz system* and *Riesz basis* without citing any other reference, except referring obliquely to her earlier work. It is conceivable that these terms were introduced by Bari. Also, in the first line of this [1951](http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/uzmu/v148/p224) comment by Gel'fand, he attributes the term *Riesz basis* to her.

Comment: Barry, Welcome to MO. Let me translate for you the first sentence of Gelfand's paper: "N. K. Bari introduced a class of bases in a Hilbert space which she called Riesz bases."